# Optional Typescript generic for function props

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to create a function whose second parameter is optional and we can indicate this generically ( if we give it its type, it is optional, if not, it is not )

```
type IpcHandlerListener<
  ListenerReturn,
  Params = unknown
> = Params extends unknown
  ? () => Promise<ListenerReturn>
  : (params: Params) => Promise<ListenerReturn>

const createIpcHandler = <ListenerReturn, Params = unknown>(
  channel: string,
  listener: IpcHandlerListener<ListenerReturn, Params>
) => {
  ipcMain.on(channel, async (event, request: IpcRequest<Params>) => {
    let ipcHandlerResponse: IpcHandlerResponse<ListenerReturn>
    try {
      const response = await listener(request?.params)

      ipcHandlerResponse = { status: 'success', data: response }
    } catch (error) {
      ipcHandlerResponse = { status: 'error', error }
    }

    event.sender.send(request.responseChannel, ipcHandlerResponse)
  })
}
```

But in this "solution" when I call the `listener` it thrown a typescript error:

> Argument of type 'Params | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Params'.   'Params' could be instantiated with an arbitrary
> type which could be unrelated to 'Params | undefined'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Params'.
> 'Params' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'

And when I try to call it in other file, like that:

```
type Props = {
  window: BrowserWindow
  options: OpenDialogOptions
}

const handler = createIpcHandler<OpenProjectPathDialogResponse, Props>(
  ipcChannels.system.getLocale,
  async ({ window, options }) => {
    return dialog.showOpenDialog(window, options)
  }
)
```

thrown this error:

> Argument of type '({ window, options }: { window: any; options: any;
> }) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter
> of type '() => Promise'

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzsMBjAsgQ2AOwDRwDyYApjgCLCYA2EA5gEokwCuUOAajSyQQEJQIAdwDOJKAHVcAE2EFiZSjXrEYwCDhEFpVWnTgBfOADNBIOAHIS1EqhiCcFgFBPcMcccyoScAJJomAEceERgAHgAFTChMEBE4AF44FhwAaxxhHAA%20RCc4OCgSEUhNEgBhAAtMHBxrAC44UKhcOjy4MGjYkQB%20BqiYuKcDFxgAT1I-NAAJaukbKCZijTEw8kwYTETknGkSY1wSaRyEtoAfXPzLxo3WEQaLERZUbxERZyv86XXMBrWNtvyw3y5wQAMuoXWLDulnEgig7w%20sOgDSaLTBwycYwm-lQMx28wAMsBQmRxGE2kSSbUFsw2Pg2v0ulsUulMk5jnBGXE4CQAB7uHbxFkZIQ4NrdOAACgAlIkchEzMSSGFKQLxExWOwsm0GpKOgNoVyRLKEvLFStVaSaZrsi5UMt4KhCusSDi8XNxFsVcS1da6QQjcy0iLspK2qgqjV6tdmjg6Hg2tQfVaGm7ZoTk9TvVT1bT2AHOnFtSacqD8igMNgcAA6DSSiPVWrUAiYESjHCoKUkABuZBgBEKwSKMFTARIQ9CkULIiyJYulxs8Ar7vmixKYlHuPTuaWpWzvo1dO1V3so3nV3tmnghV3Yi2mCE2HgSZzUElg5CMG61f1XWlLg%20ZBpm3Glbx8JIkAhW57keZ4ijebRvgaG91x8IFLiMVB1gjLsoDhWUyw%20ZcQLXZZwMQa5IWhKw8OgCwCCRKBDHRADLh7PtqzEHZxE4shpHfcdP2rFCyMqRtrAIYj8R3VD-0Bf8MSxHwFQgMB4ggtohBkYQGgEYQxEkbShDaVS1GWBoFAoXQVDAMzNCGO0HTgSMPSYpInRIF002kqAwkspQ9EPdguGoHgA0ENSsjDfILFUxRrLoei2lbdtO0lJAtJ2OQ4FM9RNEMOdCPyQobTgHRlDoTiKmEfyEslTLZCEAhcuWOTmOlIA) link for this

Comment: What are `ipcMain`, `IpcRequest` and `IpcHandlerResponse`? Please paste a reproducible code. Please paste a link to [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: Thank for your comment, I added a playground link into the  question

Comment: `unknown` is a top type. So every other type extends `unknown`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UCuA7A1ig9gdxVCAHsBCgCYDOy6WuUA-FMAE5LQBcUAZgIYA250APSDGLCAChQkKAE0EUcswCWKAOb4iJClQw48DZqygce-ISMMSp0AFryA3gF8NxMpVS7aBsca58BUMKirJLgtgCM8twoIC5a7tR69MHsfmaBFmKh0jYATPIoEABuEExxbjo0+im+pgFBluJAA) . But the in the conditional type, the resulting type is an intersection if both returns are function. That's strange behaviour. [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3A9Aw)